# I can't downgrade webview nor update it because I'm locked out of play store. What can I do?

Tags: updates, webview

My mom's phone (yes, I know what you're thinking :-) suffered from the webview update glitch yesterday.

She thought that for whatever reasons it might have something to do with her credentials, so she set a new password from another device.

I know about the fix for that glitch, but can't do much about it using the recommended methods because now she's locked out of her Google account on her phone. Obviously, trying to update her credentials on her phone must bring webview which doesn't work.

It does sound like some kind of catch 22 that my very limited knowledge can't help me getting out of.

Any help would greatly appreciated, thanks for your attention.

Comment: If it is just for Play Store access you can create another Google account on device and this time save and write down user name and password!

Comment: Thanks for your reply Robert. Well I can't do any of that because I wouldn't be able to log into that account on the phone because that would bring the webview glitch back.

Comment: You can try to install Chrome respectively Android System WebView app (depends on the Android version which one is used for displaying WebViews) manually e.g. from ApkPure.com ApkMirror.com or a similar site. The web browser if not shown as WebView works, only the WebView itself is bugged.

Comment: I'm not certain of fully understanding you, do I need to try and bypass webview in favour of chrome ? Chrome is already installed on the phone and it seems to work fine, but how can I use it to log her back into her Google account on the phone ?

Comment: Chrome stand-alone works without problems, but if Chrome is used as System WebView component every app that uses it will crash if you have the defect version installed. I had this situation on my device. But this assumes Chrome is used as WebView provider. You can check which app is used as WebView in Android Developer Options (hidden by default).

Comment: Thanks Robert. I've enabled developer options, and went to see which app is used as webview provider. It's Chrome, the other option being webview itself but it appears to be disabled and can't be selected.

Comment: Then you have to upgrade chrome to the latest version to fix the WebView problem.

Comment: It worked, thanks Robert !

Answer (score 0):

I've just done what @Robert wisely advised me to do which is to use an APK app to install the newest copy of Chrome to my mom's phone and thus benefit from the bug free version of webview to update her credentials and regain control of her phone. That's worked a treat.

Thanks Robert :-)